# Install ipython with pip on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, pip, ipython

When I want to install **ipython** with **pip** on my new **Ubuntu 16.04** installation, I get this:

```
$ pip install ipython --user
Collecting ipython
  Downloading ipython-5.4.1-py2-none-any.whl (757kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 757kB 821kB/s 
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython)
  Downloading pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython)
  Downloading simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
Collecting traitlets>=4.2 (from ipython)
  Downloading traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" (from ipython)
  Downloading backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from ipython)
  Downloading decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from ipython)
  Downloading Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 829kB/s 
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython)
  Downloading pexpect-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" (from ipython)
  Downloading pathlib2-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython)
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 (from ipython)
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-1.0.14-py2-none-any.whl (248kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 1.1MB/s 
Collecting enum34; python_version == "2.7" (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
  Downloading enum34-1.1.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython-genutils (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
  Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython)
  Downloading ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython)
  Downloading scandir-1.5.tar.gz
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython)
  Downloading wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: simplegeneric, scandir
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for simplegeneric ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/manu/.cache/pip/wheels/7b/31/08/c85e74c84188cbec6a6827beec4d640f2bd78ae003dc1ec09d
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scandir ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dPd3d3/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpDLgZXopip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  copying scandir.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_scandir' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _scandir.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_scandir.o
  _scandir.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scandir
  Running setup.py clean for scandir
Successfully built simplegeneric
Failed to build scandir
Installing collected packages: six, scandir, pathlib2, pickleshare, simplegeneric, enum34, decorator, ipython-genutils, traitlets, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, pygments, ptyprocess, pexpect, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, ipython
  Running setup.py install for scandir ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dPd3d3/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-H_p3nS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    copying scandir.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_scandir' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c _scandir.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_scandir.o
    _scandir.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dPd3d3/scandir/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-H_p3nS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dPd3d3/scandir/
```

The interesting line is:

```
Failed building wheel for scandir
```

How could I get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

And then try again:

```
$ pip install ipython --user
```

It should work now.

Comment: I tried this, and the installation seemed to go fine. But when I type ipython in the command line, it says ipython is not installed! Do you by any chance know  how to fix that?

Comment: Could you give me the output of the command **$ which ipython**.
Or could you try with **$ $HOME/.local/bin/ipython** ?

Comment: Could you help me to understand, why did you use ` --user` in the above command?

Comment: If you use '--user', pip will install ipython in this directory: $HOME/.local/bin/. So you don't need root privileges, and only you (and not other users) will be able to use ipython. If you don't use '--user', pip will install ipython for all users, and you may need root privileges to do that.

Please find more information here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same `Failed building wheel for scandir` error on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. The root problem was that gcc wasn't installed and it's used for building `scandir`.

After I installed gcc the problem went away:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

I think the OP's issue is related to missing header files (not missing gcc), but I thought I'd mention this here as users missing gcc will probably also find this page.