# How do you use ipython with pip --user installed libraries?

Tags: python, pip, ipython

I am going through a book which uses libraries that are not packaged through apt-get. Hence, I need to use pip, as [this](https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/installing_on_debian.html) explains quite nicely. In order to maintain stability of the core system, I am advised by the aforementioned article to use "pip --user" to install python packages.

I want to use IPython.

After reading [Manu's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922302/install-ipython-with-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04), I know how to install IPython through pip. However, I am unable to discover how to run IPython after that step, and it is unclear to me whether it will then also allow me to use the libraries installed through "pip install --user"

Hence: How do you use ipython with pip --user installed libraries?

To pose the whole, same question, in a different manner;

Manu, after reading [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/922302/install-ipython-with-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04), this is my question:

"And then, how do you use that installed version of ipython? I'm coming from running ipython3 directly in terminal, but I need the "bleeding edge" pip version of ipython, in order to be able to use pip installed libraries in ipython. Is that possible?"

Comment: More importantly; how do I delete my own questions? This needs to go on stackoverflow, not askubuntu. Hence why Manu had to answer his own question, and got downvoted into obvlion. Sorry!

Comment: Install ipython in the python virtual environment and run from there, I suppose!

Comment: Seems recursive. Is that a joke?

Comment: There's no reason to delete. You're not asking a python question, really, you are asking a question about the python interpreter and it's big brother, ipython. These are programs running on Ubuntu and therefore on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255944/how-do-you-use-ipython-with-pip-user-installed-libraries/45269422#45269422). Credit due to Griboullis.

> In Ubuntu, `pip install --user` installs the `ipython` executable in the `$HOME/.local/bin` directory. This directory needs to be added to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It prepares your python environment. Python, Ipyhton, pip and some libraries are installed with it.